# new Scanner(parameter), don't understand

Tags: java

So I'm doing my homework right now. I'm learning from Big Java Late Objects. There is an assignment that says the following:

```
public boolean checkAnswer(String response) {
    Scanner parser = new Scanner(response);
    ArrayList<String> correctAnswersSeen = new ArrayList<String>();
    int totalAnswers = 0;
    while (parser.hasNext()) {
        String answer = parser.next();
        if (this.allAnswers.contains(answer) && !correctAnswersSeen.contains(answer)) {
            correctAnswersSeen.add(answer);
        }
        totalAnswers += 1;
    parser.close();
    }
    return correctAnswersSeen.size() == this.allAnswers.size() && totalAnswers == allAnswers.size();
}
```

I really don't understand the first two lines. Ok, I'm getting it that their is a new boolean method named checkAnswer with a String as a parameter.

But what comes at line after that: `Scanner parser = new Scanner(response)`. What does that mean? Normally I use `new Scanner(System.in)`, I understand that.

But what's up with using a parameter from the method in the `new Scanner` object?

Comment: have you check java api what scanner class comments say?

Comment: The parameter is the thing to scan.

Comment: I understand it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the input string comes into the `Scanner`.

See [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String))

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified string.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `source` - A string to scan

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now :)